# Android Studio no tools.jar found

Tags: android, tools.jar

I use the latest version of Android Studio. If I try to build an APK then I get the following error message: "Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for Android API 32 Platform (/home/stefan/Android/Sdk)". But it is not told where Android Studio searches for "tools.jar"!

I already did put these env assigns into "studio.sh":

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk

How can this be fixed to find "tools.jar"?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution: go to "File/Project Structure" and select "SDK/Android API 32 Platform". Now set "Java SDK" to "openjdk-18" if it is installed. Now click on "openjdk-18" on the left side. Now add from the "lib" folder inside the "openjdk" the file "tools.jar".

If everything was set right, now Android Studio should find "tools.jar"!